# Typewriter effect goes full width

Tags: css

I copied a typewriter effect that is created purely in CSS but the animation of the blinking caret is moving over the full width of the page, while it should stop at the end of the text. I have a code snippet here: https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-currying-20bko?file=/src/styles.css

Anyone suggestions to fix this issue?

Comment: Change `width: 100%` to `width: max-content`?

Comment: The only solution I could find was to change your div container into a flexbox with display : inline-flex; flex-direction: column; align-items : flex-start; and then nest your typewriter into a div of its own

Comment: @m4n0 unfortunately that doesn't work. You can see the effect of that in the codesandbox.

Comment: @DSteman I just verified it through the answer. It may work on the container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the paragraph text within a container and give it a [`width: max-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-content)

App.js:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <p className="title">This piece of text is fixed</p>
      <div className="typewriter-container"> <!-- Wrapper -->
        <p className="typewriter">typewriter text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

CSS:

```
.typewriter-container {
  width: max-content;
}
```

Demo:

[image]

Output:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1r8S.jpg